# Cannot find symbol class error

Tags: android

I have problem i have added new class in `Library` called `ExpandableTextView`. Now when i have to use this class i have imported it in my `MainActivity.class` like this `import com.image.ExpandableTextView;` and when i run my app it shows me this error. 
`cannot find symbol class ExpandableTextView`. It gets weird because in Library there is also another class in the same package and imported like this: `import com.image.SlidingLayer;` But it does not show the error and it is used in MainActivity. Has anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: Please add some of you code.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the class modifier for ExpandableTextView set to private or package-local?